# PHP a form inside a button

Tags: php, forms

is it possible to put a form input in a button so that when i click it will pass the id to the next page . Current my button is generated by a database i need to put the DeviceId in to a hiddenfield in the button to pass to another page . Thanks

```
 while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $fetch ) ) {
            $sResults .= '<tr id="'. $row->DeviceID . '">';
            $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->DeviceID . '</td>';
            $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->Model . '</td>';
            $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->manufacturer . '</td>';
            $sResults .= '<td>' .'<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON value="Add to My List">'. '</td>';
```

Comment: Use a regular link eg `<a href="yourpage.php?id=yourid">Add</a>` You can style it like a button with css if needed

Comment: That works, with Bootstrap you don't need to create a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Shove it into the `action` of the `<form>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can't make this, but you can make a hidden input.

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="NAMEOFVALUE" VALUE="3">
```

Add this to your normal form and it will pass this information to ther server, and the visitor of the page can't see this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<form action="url/to/redirect?foo=bar">
  <input type="BUTTON" value="Add to My List"/>
</form>
```

You can either set the action value to pass the parameters you need or add hidden input fields:

```
<form action="url/to/redirect" method="POST">
  <input name"foo1" type="BUTTON" value="bar1"/>
  <input name"foo2" type="BUTTON" value="bar2"/>
  <input type="BUTTON" value="Add to My List"/>
</form>
```

While you're at it, you might want to escape the other values, so that you'll avoid XSS attacks [1]

1 - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/